# "blinking" boolean with system.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: java

Why is this value always true? I just can't figure out how to have a boolean that "blinks" every second.

```
long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
boolean blink = (Math.floor(millis/1000 + 0.5)==Math.floor(millis/1000));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I'd do it

```
  long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
  boolean blink = (millis % 2000) < 1000;
```

This uses the modulo `%` operator to determine how far into a repeating two second window the current time is. Then it sees if it's in the first half (0 to 999) of the window or the second half (1000 to 1999). This will result in a boolean value that alternates true and false every second.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Will accept your answer once possible (in 5 minutes or so)

Answer (score 2):

The variable `millis` is of type `long`, which is an integer type, so `millis/1000` is truncated to an integer value *before* the 0.5 is added.

An easier way to do what you want might be:

```
boolean blink = ((millis / 1000) & 1) == 0;
```

This converts the millisecond value to seconds (by dividing by 1000), then testing the lowest bit to see whether it is 0.